# Redirect specific URL before other redirects take place in .htaccess?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

The canonical website URL will be `https://www.example.com`

Typically any requests eg for `https://example.com` will be redirected to `https://www.example.com` by WordPress site settings.

However, I have a special requirement from a team member regarding an email server need.

**Specifically** they need any requests made to this URL: `https://example.com/foo` to be redirected to `https://foo.example.com`.

To avoid some kind of weird chain or loop happening (or even slowness), I was thinking of placing a redirect rule somewhere near the top of the .htaccess file (ie above the other rules) to facilitate this particular redirect *before* anything else happens.

a) Would that work, and b) would this code be an acceptable way of doing it?

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On

#my code
Redirect 301 /foo https://foo.example.com

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do `example.com` and `foo.example.com` point to different hosts (different file systems)? "`https://example.com/foo` to be redirected" - As well as `www.example.com`? What about URLs of the form `/foo/<something>`? What is consuming this redirect? Is it a "browser" or some API call or sometihng?

Comment: Thanks for the question. foo.example.com will be used by IT dept for a Microsoft Exchange thing (I don't fully understand it, but they say they need requests to example.com/foo redirected to foo.example.com.

Comment: "used by IT dept for a Microsoft Exchange thing" - that almost sounds like the request should perhaps be _forwarded_ "internally", rather than an external "redirect"?

Answer (score 2):

> a) Would that work, and b) would this code be an acceptable way of
> doing it?

Yes.

But you should put the custom directive (the `Redirect` line) **above the `BEGIN` marker**, i.e. the `# BEGIN WordPress` line, because if not, then your custom directive will be gone when the WordPress rewrite rules are flushed/regenerated.

So:

```
# your code here:
Redirect 301 /foo https://foo.example.com

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
# ... WordPress rewrite rules here.
# END WordPress
```

But if the subdomain is in a directory in the document root of the *main domain* (`example.com`), then you would want to use the following which prevents `foo.example.com/foo` from being *redirected to `foo.example`*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ https://foo.example.com/ [L,R=301,NC,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
# ... WordPress rewrite rules here.
# END WordPress
```

And if you wanted to redirect anything in `example.com/foo`, e.g. `example.com/foo/some-file` to `foo.example.com/some-file`, then you can change the above `RewriteRule` line to: (i.e. You basically just need to play with the rewrite rule's regular expression.)

```
RewriteRule ^f(/(.*))?$ https://foo.example.com/$2 [L,R=301,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Sally I will have to try this out and get back to you!

Comment: "to prevent `foo.example.com/foo` from redirecting" - The `RedirectMatch` directive as posted won't prevent that.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite. I was confused with my own tests..

Comment: @Drewdavid, I've corrected the mistake in my answer, but then I made a small typo in the `RewriteRule ^f(` - that "f" should be "foo".. and I'll correct that, but after I received your reply.

Comment: I would certainly go with the mod_rewrite solution (+1), rather than the mod_alias `Redirect` directive here. Whilst the `Redirect` as posted "works" in a _browser_ context, it is dependent on the browser "fixing" the target URL, since the slash after the target hostname is missing. (From comments above, it is not clear how this redirect is being used... "used by IT dept for a Microsoft Exchange thing") The `Redirect` directive is also prefix-matching, so `/foo/bar` will be redirected to `https://foo.example.com/bar`, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: The `Redirect` directive is also processed _after_ other mod_rewrite directives, despite placing the rule at the top of the file. (mod_alias is processed _after_ mod_rewrite.) So, at best, it is marginally less efficient (if prioritising the redirect - which seems to be a requirement) and at worst you can get unexpected conflicts with any existing redirects that use mod_rewrite's `RewriteRule`.

Comment: @MrWhite, I was just saying the `Redirect` directive does work, and I placed it at the very top just because it should be put outside the WordPress rewrite rules. But anyway, you might want to post your comments as an answer?